# Make a molex to USB Female power cable?

Tags: usb, soldering, led-strip, conversion

Could I recreate this molex to female USB cable by cutting off the molex connector of a fan and the female end of an USB extension, then solder the red and black wires together?

If it's possible, would it be safe if I heatshrink or electrical tape it?

I was looking to power a $5 RGB LED strip for a PC that's powered via a male USB-A and controlled with a little RF remote. It looks similar to this: [https://www.amazon.com/RGBZONE-RGBZONE-1m-USB-DC-5V-24V-LED-Controller-Kit-17-Key-RF-Wireless-Remote-Control-Dimmer-Inline-LED-Controller-for-5050-3528-RGB-LED-Strip-Lights/dp/B07D3KJN4B/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D3KJN4B)
[image]

Comment: The datasheet will give the answer. Sadly, no datasheet, no answer.

Comment: Perhaps you should re-word the question, because we don't know if you can or not. At least you should be able to measure the wiring so that you are sure you don't mix up ground, 5V, and 12V at the molex connector, and you know which pins at the USB connector are ground and 5V. The colour might not always mean the same thing. e.g. yellow of the ATX supply is 12V, but fan might have red for 12V. The LED controller also draws an insane amount of current (12A) and many USB connectors and cables are meant only for 500mA, so to me it sounds very dubious product to have USB connector.